# Can you please see if you can figure out these errors I am having?

Tags: vb.net

I was fortunate to have one of the experts here help me with this code but I have not been able to get it to work. I am receiving all kinds of errors. First, here is the code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports EO.Pdf
Imports System.Collections.Specialized

Partial Class getParcels
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public Function Download() As FileResult
        // Populate list with urls 
    Dim urls = New List(Of String)() With { _
        "C:\1.html", _
        "C:\2.html" _
    }

        Dim documents = New List(Of EO.Pdf.PdfDocument)()
        For Each url As var In urls
            Dim doc = New EO.Pdf.PdfDocument()
            EO.Pdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(url, doc)
            documents.Add(doc)
        Next

        Dim mergedDocument As EO.Pdf.PdfDocument = EO.Pdf.PdfDocument.Merge(documents.ToArray())

        Dim ms = New MemoryStream()
        mergedDocument.Save(ms)
        ms.Position = 0

        Return New FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf") With { _
         .FileDownloadName = "download.pdf" _
        }
    End Function
```

This code is intended to allow us to several urls at same time, separating them with comas and merging them into one pdf document.  It gives error that fileResult is not define.

On the following:

```
C:\1.html
C:\2.html
```

it says `name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with ','`

Then type var is not defined, urls must be declared, type MemoryStream is not defined, type FileStreamResult is not defined. It seems to me that there is a System import that is missing. This is part of Essential Objects html to pdf component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `From`,

```
  Dim urls = New List(Of String)() From
      {
       "C:\1.html",
       "C:\2.html"
      }
```

Or

```
 Dim urls = New List(Of String)(
            {
              "C:\1.html",
              "C:\2.html"
            })
```

Comment: thank you veru much for your kindness. That fixed it.

If I need to grab the values from querystring and separate the values with comma, any ideas what to change?

Also, do you know how to fix the other issues?

Comment: If it is comma delimited that use `String.Split(delemiterString)` method and if it is  `url?n=a&b=2` then [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring.aspx)

Comment: it is going to be both. First the url like default.aspx?n=a&b=2 then , then next one default.aspx?n=c&b=4. Total number of urls will depend on how many checkboxes users click on